# Where is the .ctags file on Windows?

Tags: windows, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm trying to use ctags with my python project, but am running into the problem that ctags recognizes import lines as definitions. The advice I found was to add the line:

--python-kinds=-iv

to my ~/.ctags file. However, I'm doing this from a Windows machine and can't find the equivalent  of the .ctags file. I've tried looking in my $HOME dir as well as my ctags dir. I've tried to google the issue, but haven't had any luck.

Is this a file I need to create myself and if so, where should I put it? In the same dir as the tags file I'm creating?

Answer (score 3):

The *HOMEDRIVE* and *HOMEPATH* environment variables define the *$HOME* location.

This [page](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=3367) shows an example of setting up the ctags *$HOME* on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The [sysinternals process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) is afair the windows equivalent strace; fire it up and watch what files ctags is looking for at startup.